# Get panel from button inside and change TableLayoutPanel cell color

Tags: vb.net, winforms, panel, tablelayoutpanel

I have a `TableLayoutPanel`, panel in each cell, 2 `RadioButton` in each panel. When I checked the RadioButton, the cell color will change. I know I can do it with assign `CheckedChanged` event to each RadioButton and hardcode the cell row and column to change the color. I have 15 panels, so will have 30 different `CheckedChanged` event.

Is there any way that I can use the `sender(RadioButton)` to get its panel? So that I can use `GetCellPosition(panel)` to get the cell and use the panel to get which RadioButton in it is checked. Then I can just assign this event to all RadioButtons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can be achieved by using the [`Control.Parent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.parent) property.

Your code should look something like this:

```
Private Sub RBs_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton1.CheckedChanged,
                                                                         RadioButton2.CheckedChanged,
                                                                         ' ...etc.
    Dim rb = DirectCast(sender, RadioButton)
    Dim pnl = DirectCast(rb.Parent, Panel)
    
    ' TODO: Do something with pnl and/or rb.
    Console.WriteLine(pnl.Name)
End Sub
```

Do note, however, that selecting a certain RadioButton will trigger the `CheckedChanged` event for *two* RBs; the one that got checked and the one the got unchecked. So, you might want to wrap your code inside `If rb.Checked Then ... End If` or whatever is appropriate.